# How to subset row values by string label in a single column in R?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, gsub

I have a column that I would like to subset its row value based on the first and last 'string' label in R. The level values are as followed:

```
[1] "60022 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Snacks)"
[3] "60024 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Lg Snacks)"
[5] "60027 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Sml Snacks)"
```

I would like the to pull the # and the last string separated by the ';'. Is there a function or syntax in R to do this? So remove "Location; 9TH FLOOR" and just keep the last ; "" string.

I have tried this to pull just the first value but am unable to keep the "snacks" as well with this code:

```
#updated_df_2020$Machine <- sub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", updated_df_2020$Machine)
```

End result for each row should be the number (60022 and then Snacks) like so:

```
[1] "60022 (Snacks)" 
[1] "60024 (Lg Snacks)" 
[1] "60027 (Sml Snacks)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to remove the substring, capture the digits (`\\d+`) at the start (`^`) of the string, and then capture the non white space (`\\S`) that succeeds the `;` and zero or more space (`\\s*`) and other characters that follows (`.*`) till the `)`at the end (`$`) as second capture group. In the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`, `\\2`) of the captured group and modify it by adding the `(`

```
updated_df_2020$Machine <- sub("^(\\d+)\\b.*;\\s*\\b(\\S.*\\))$", 
        "\\1 (\\2", updated_df_2020$Machine)
updated_df_2020$Machine
#[1] "60022 (Snacks)"     "60024 (Lg Snacks)"  "60027 (Sml Snacks)"
```

If the start of the string is not a digit and still wants to get extract, replace (`(\\d+)`) with `(\\w+)`

#### data

```
updated_df_2020 <- data.frame(Machine = c("60022 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Snacks)",
   "60024 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Lg Snacks)", "60027 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Sml Snacks)"),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - since there are unique numbers and values (snacks, drinks, bottled drinks, etc...) is there a way to normalize it to just take first value and last value in ()? @akrun

Comment: Appreciate the clear answer! Thank you! Would it be possible to take the last 2 words in the (; ; Bottled Bev) instead of just 'Bev'? Would I just do "\\2 (\\2" instead of \\1? @akrun?

Comment: sure it can be done   can you please update your post with all the rules

Comment: Updated/ sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
> a <- c("60022 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Snacks)", "60024 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Snacks)", "60027 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Snacks)")
> strs <- strsplit(a, split = " ")
> sapply(strs, function(s) paste(s[1], paste0("(", s[length(s)])))
#
# "60022 (Snacks)" "60024 (Snacks)" "60027 (Snacks)"
#
```

which is uglier, but i guess a bit easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the number at the begining and everything followed by colon afterwards using `sub` :

```
sub("(\\d+).*;(.*)", "\\1 (\\2", x)
#[1] "60022 ( Snacks)"     "60024 ( Lg Snacks)"  "60027 ( Sml Snacks)"
```

where x is

```
x <- c("60022 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Snacks)", 
       "60024 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Lg Snacks)",
       "60027 (Location; 9TH FLOOR; Sml Snacks)")
```